# Do we lose orthogonality of Bessel functions when we change interval

Tags: orthogonality, bessel-functions

This is the basic definition of integral when you calculate integral product of orthogonal Bessel functions.

> [image: Link to photo of equation of the problem]

What happens when you change integral bounds from [0,a] to [b,c]? Do you lose the orthogonality or does it remain? What is the solution of the same integral only with boundaries [b,c]

P.S.: This is my initial equation.

> [image: Initial version of equation]

Cs and Ds are unknown constants, but i can express Ds with using Cs - Cs is the constant i am looking for. Xs and sn are determined numerically i can easily determine them, not the point.
The plan (according to what we did in school) is that i multiply this with orthogonal function and integrate it so only m=n product give non-zero integrals.

> [image: Equation under integral with orthogonal product]

How am i supposed to solve this problem if the functions are not orthogonal? How can i find Cs?

P.S. P.S.: This is the correlation between Cs and Ds.

> [image]

Comment: Correct, you lose orthogonality.

Comment: Is it the possible to redo the integral to regain orthogonality?

Comment: What you have is really a linear system. One approach to solving it is to use functional Gram-Schmidt, which is equivalent to doing a QR decomposition of a matrix $A$ in $Ax=b$ and then writing $x=R^{-1} Q^T b$, or you can use $R^\dagger$ if $R$ is not invertible. This method has the advantage of automatically doing least squares if the problem actually has no solution. But it is not the only way to go. Another way to go is to take inner products with a basis of the 40 dimensional subspace that you're interested in, which will give 40 equations in the 40 unknowns.

Comment: (Cont.) The latter is the same as what you do in the case when the basis is already orthogonal, except that when the basis is orthogonal, the system you get is diagonal.

Comment: Could you please explain it in a bit of a more simple way, on a level of a high-school student? Perhaps on a easy yet similar example? Also, english is not my primary language, so i am a bit struggling with understading complex terms.

Comment: I have also added a correlation between Cs and Ds, so technically everything there is to need to know up to this stage. Sn are numerically determined values, i have them know, they are unperiodical.

Comment: One more question: Do I even have to multiply with "orthogonal function" in this case if there is no orthogonality? The whole point of multiplying with orthogonal function is that after integration you only get components when m=n, other integrals are zero.

Comment: If you use the second method I described, you can pick whatever basis of the 40 dimensional space you care about to multiply through by. If you do the first method then you will assemble an orthogonal basis first.

Comment: I am sorry, i still don't understand what you are trying to say. Can you show me on a simple example, on a smaller scale

Comment: Simpler example: say you had $c_1 \cos(x) + c_2 \sin(x)=f(x)$. You can get a system of equations for $c_1,c_2$ as $c_1 \langle \cos(x),\cos(x) \rangle + c_2 \langle \cos(x),\sin(x) \rangle = \langle \cos(x),f(x) \rangle$ and $c_1 \langle \sin(x),\cos(x) \rangle + c_2 \langle \sin(x),\sin(x) \rangle = \langle \sin(x),f(x) \rangle$. This system is diagonal if $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ are orthogonal, but it is still solvable even if it isn't diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

Take $a=1$.  Consider the first two zeros of $J_0$; call then $a_{01}$ and $a_{02}$.
Then
$$
\int_0^T J_0(a_{01}\rho)J_0(a_{02}\rho)\rho\;d\rho 
=
\frac{a_{01}J_1( a_{01}T)J_0(a_{02}T) - a_{02}J_0(a_{01}T)J_1(a_{02}T)}{(a_{01}^2 - a_{02}^2)}\;T
$$
If we put $T=1$, then both numerator terms vanish, because we get $J_0(a_{01})=0$ and
$J_0(a_{02})=0$.  If we use some other value of $T$, we do not get these zero terms.

Comment: I have made an edit in my question to widen the presented problem i am facing.